# Disabling Analytics for Web Forms for marketers

Tags: sitecore, analytics, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, web-forms-for-marketers

I have a solution where analytics is disabled (Sitecore.Analytics.config has been renamed to .disabled), but if I try to use the demo form that comes with Web Forms for Marketers the following error is being thrown.

```
8204 11:28:03 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.layouts_custom_baselayout_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\ab561fab\3efac5d0\App_Web_nzwz3knl.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'Sitecore.Analytics.ITracker Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.get_Current()'.
Source: Sitecore.Forms.Core
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.Ascx.Controls.SimpleForm.OnAddInitOnClient()
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.Ascx.Controls.SimpleForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to disable analytics from WFFM
in config file Sitecore.Forms.cong into setting section add

I hope is helpful

Comment: "Analytics.Enabled" value="false"

Answer (score 1):

In the Form Designer, push the Properties in the Analytics sections there you can disable the "Enable Marketing Analytics" for a specific form.